# Add a space in string between time and am/pm in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

My data in a pandas DataFrame looks like this:

```
   time
10:00am
11:00am
12:30pm
 1:45pm
10:00pm
```

My desired output is:

```
    time
10:00 am
11:00 am
12:30 pm
 1:45 pm
10:00 pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.replace`:

```
df['time'].str.replace(r'(am|pm)', r' \1')
```

Or as @Kartik suggests, `Series.replace` can do the same thing:

```
df['time'].replace(to_replace=r'(am|pm)', value=r' \1', regex=True)
```

Or slicing and concatenation:

```
df['time'].str[:-2] + ' ' + df['time'].str[-2:]
```

Both produce the new column:

```
0    10:00 am
1    11:00 am
2    12:30 pm
3     1:45 pm
4    10:00 pm
Name: time, dtype: object
```

As an aside, if you're working with times and/or dates pandas has very good support for datetime and timedelta types. These are much easier to work with than string types if you're doing analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I appreciate it.yes I'm doing data analysis.

Comment: @kaleshanagineni: glad it helped. If you feel your current question has been answered satisfactorily, you can mark any answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer) (there should be a tick mark next the answer). Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @ajcr: Why not just `df['time'].replace()`? See here: [DataFrame.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: @Kartik: that `replace` method can only replace entire entries in a Series or DataFrame that match a particular value or pattern with a new value. It doesn't allow the string to be modified in the way that `str.replace` does.

Comment: Ooooh! Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Kartik: actually I'm mistaken and you were right! This works the same way: `df['time'].replace(to_replace=r'(am|pm)', value=r' \1', regex=True)`. Looks like I forgot about the `regex` kwarg - my bad.

Comment: I guessed it should work. I used `replace` before, though not with regex. Didn't try it myself. Thanks!